# MVC 5 application RDLC Report throws an exception after hosting but works fine with visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, rdlc, reportviewerformvc

Here are the both exception and the inner exception messages plus stack trace. This is works really fine when I run with visual studio. I have used **ReportViewerForMvc** and installed via Nuget. So I do have all the .dll referenced. Only issue is it is not working once I hosted with unoeuro.

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
>   ASP.reportviewerwebform_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>        An error occurred during local report processing.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
>   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.GetParameters()    at
>   ReportViewerForMvc.ReportViewerExtensions.SetProperties(LocalReport
>   localReport, LocalReport properties)    at
>   ReportViewerForMvc.ReportViewerExtensions.SetProperties(ReportViewer
>   reportViewer, ReportViewer properties)    at
>   ReportViewerForMvc.ReportViewerWebForm.BuildReportViewer()    at
>   ReportViewerForMvc.ReportViewerWebForm.Page_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Please help me to solve this.  I have already gone through many threads but couldn't find a solution

Comment: Possible that the RDLC Report File was not properly deployed to target environment, or doesn't reside in the expected folder (relative paths) when the executing directory changes

Comment: Bingo !!! I forgot to check that. Yes that was the issue. Put it as the answer. I will accept !!!  How to make it always publish ?  Can I achieve it by making Copy to Output Directory - Copy always ?

Comment: added my answer, with MSDeploy based deployment, I think `Copy if newer` is sufficient in our case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without really knowing what the cause *is*, I can guess what it *could* be. It's possible that the RDLC Report File (e.g. `MyReport.rdlc`) was not properly deployed to target environment, or doesn't reside in the expected folder (relative paths) when the executing directory changes.

In Visual Studio, ensure that `Copy to Output Directory` Property is set to `Copy if newer/always`, and when executing on IIS, the Files could appear within `\bin` directory, while locally, they're probably within `bin\Debug`.

When passing in the File name of `MyReport.rdlc`, in our application, we make it configurable and construct the path like this:

```
var rdlcFullPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportingPath"], "MyReport.rdlc");
```

In the `web.config` file, add the Path setting:

```
<add key="ReportingPath" value="bin\Reports" />
```

You can override the setting for every environment to match the target structure.